# Which part of this movement code should I apply delta time?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
 this.up = function () {
  this.velocity += this.lift;
  };
 this.update = function () {
   this.velocity += this.gravity;

   this.velocity *= 0.9;
   this.y += this.velocity;

  }
```

Hi, so I have this code in my canvas draw loop to make a shape move up and down, the thing is so its frame rate dependent so im trying to apply delta time to these functions. Anyone know how I'd go about doing that?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe you need to check a minimum amount of time has passed? `if(deltaTime > minTime) { this.up() }`?

Comment: delta is a factor for the distance in pixels. 60 FPS should give a delta of 0.01666, for instance. So a speed of 50 pixels per second translates into a speed of 50 * 0.01666 pixels per frame. Which most likely means you need to do `this.velocity += this.lift * delta;` and `this.velocity += this.gravity * delta;`

Comment: So i wouldnt have to apply delta when changing the y and the *= 0.9?

Comment: No, definitely not. As a rule of thumb, delta only gets applied to values that are **added**, never to factors. And `this.velocity` is already reduced by delta, so when changing this.y, you don't need to implement delta again.

Comment: Note that you can also use per-second speeds for lift, gravity and velocity instead and only do `this.y += this.velocity * delta;` instead, i.e. only use delta when you change the position.

Comment: @ChrisG Hmm it didnt seem to work, If I change the fps of the game the physics still perform differently

My code looks like this   this.up = function () {
    this.velocity += this.lift * deltaTime;
  };
  this.update = function () {
    this.velocity += this.gravity * deltaTime;

    this.velocity *= 0.9;

    this.y += this.velocity;
}

Comment: is it because the velocity is still being reduced by 0.9? Cause wouldnt the *= 0.9 be called a certain amount of times depending on their frame rate still?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/q1e6y5gz/ Multiplying the velocity by 0.9 is a heavy amount of drag, try something closer to 1. However subtracting a fixed amount is actual physics, afaik, and then you can once again multiply by delta.

Comment: I was lookin at how you get delta, is that in milliseconds? Cause on p5 js using deltaTime is returned in milliseconds. when I console log your delta its 0.007, and when I console log p5 js' deltaTime it's an average of 14. When I tried using your exact movement code it came out way different which im guessing its because of how the delta is calculated maybe?

Answer (score 0):

[`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) calls its callback with a timestamp. This allows you to track the time passed between two frames:

```js
let t = null;

const frame = dt => {
  // Update and render your canvas
};

const loop = ts => {
  const dt = t === null ? 0 : ts - t;
  t = ts;
  frame(dt / 1000);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
```

This example calls frame with the *elapsed time in seconds*. This means you can express your velocity and acceleration in `pixels/second`.

You'll get:

- position in `px`
- velocity in `px/s`
- acceleration in `px/s/s`

Updating the three becomes something like:

```
px += vx * dt;
vx += ax * dt;
```

In the example below I've implemented a quick random animation. Try increasing the entity count using the number input.

For small number of entities, we're able to render at 60fps and using the real elapsed time doesn't matter much.

But as you increase the number of entities, you'll see stuff starting to move really slowly if we don't take the elapsed time in to account!

```js
const G = 300; // px / s / s

const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
cvs.width = 300;
cvs.height = 300;
cvs.style.border = "1px solid red";

const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

const Ball = (x, y, vx = 0, vy = 0, ax = 0, ay = G, color = "black") => {
  const render = () => {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  };
  
  const update = (dt) => {
    return Ball(
      x + dt * vx,
      y + dt * vy,
      vx + dt * ax,
      vy + dt * ay,
      ax,
      ay,
      color
    );
  }
  
  return { render, update };
}

const randomBalls = n => Array.from(
  { length: n },
  () => Ball(
    Math.random() * 300,
    Math.random() * 300,
    -100 + Math.random() * 200,
    Math.random() * -200,
    0,
    G,
    `#${[
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16),
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16),
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16)
    ].join("")}`
  )
);

// Game
let balls = randomBalls(100);

let t = null;
let useFrameTime = true;

const frame = dt => {
  if (!useFrameTime) dt = 1 / 60;

  // Update entities
  balls = balls.map(b => b.update(dt));
  
  // Clear window
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  
  // Draw new rects
  balls.forEach(b => b.render());
}

const loop = ts => {
  const dt = t === null ? 0 : ts - t;
  t = ts;
  frame(dt / 1000);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

document.body.append(cvs);


requestAnimationFrame(loop);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const n = +document.querySelector("input[type=number]").value;
  balls = randomBalls(n);
});

document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  useFrameTime = e.target.checked;
});
```

```css
body { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px"> 
  <p>Increase the count here. Time for all balls to exit the frame should stay roughly the same, but you should see the frame rate drop as you increase the number of entities to render.
  </p>
  <input type="number" value="100">
  <button>Go</button>
  <br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" checked> Use frame time in render loop</label>
</div>
```